# my three bootstrap panels ain't resolving horizontally in one row

Tags: php, html

Goodday.. pls am new here.. I have a problem with my code.. I am trying to display mysql data inside three bootstrap panels...and I would want them to appear all three panel in one row.... here is my code... l don't mind my coding methods.. I'd appreciate corrections...

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top: 100px;">



        <div><!--//news slider div-->


        </div><!-- end of news slider div-->




    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-4">

            <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h1 class="">LATEST NEWS</h1>
                    </div>
                    <?php
//selesct post from database and display to frontend

                    $selectpost = "SELECT * FROM blogposts ORDER BY post_date DESC";
                    $result = mysql_query($selectpost);
                    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

                        while ($postrow = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                            $title = $postrow['post_title'];
                            $cont = $postrow['post_content'];
                            $date = $postrow['post_date'];                 
                            $author =$postrow['post_author'];
                            ?>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="content-div">
                        <h3><a href=""><?= ($title); ?></a></h3>
                        <h5 class="text-success"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Posted On:<?= ($date); ?>&nbsp;  
                            <i class="fa fa-user"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    Author:<?= ($author); ?></h5>
                            <p><?= ($cont); ?></p> 
                    </div>
                            <?php
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">

                        <h1 class="">BLOG POST</h1>
                    </div>
                    <?php
//selesct post from database and display to frontend

                    $selectpost = "SELECT * FROM blogposts ORDER BY post_date DESC";
                    $result = mysql_query($selectpost);
                    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

                        while ($postrow = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                            $title = $postrow['post_title'];
                            $cont = $postrow['post_content'];
                            ?>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="content-div">
                        <h3><a href=""><?= ($title); ?></a></h3>
                        <h5 class="text-success"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Posted On:<?= ($date); ?>&nbsp;
                        </span>  
                            <i class="fa fa-user"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    Author:<?= ($author); ?></h5>
                            <p><?= ($cont); ?></p> 
                    </div>
                            <?php
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">                         
                        <h1 class="">SIDEBAR</h1>
                    </div>
                        <?php
//selesct post from database and display to frontend

                    $selectpost = "SELECT * FROM blogposts ORDER BY post_date DESC";
                    $result = mysql_query($selectpost);
                    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

                        while ($postrow = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                            $title = $postrow['post_title'];
                            $cont = $postrow['post_content'];
                            ?>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="content-div">
                        <h3><a href=""><?= ($title); ?></a></h3>
                        <h5 class="text-success"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Posted On:&nbsp;&nbsp;<?= ($date); ?>&nbsp;  
                            <i class="fa fa-user"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            Author:&nbsp;<?= ($author); ?></h5>
                            <p><?= ($cont); ?></p> 
                    </div>
                            <?php
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div><!--end of content container-->
```

Here are some images below... pls I need help on this.. Thanks
..
Sorry I am finding it hard in uploading the images... Thanks

Comment: Can you post a sample of the generated HTML as a code snippet?

Comment: Another question - which version of bootstrap are you using? V3 or V4?  If I correctly reproduced your code, the basic bootstrap setup of the HTML, in my codepen project, it will work with V3, and not with V4. You can see it here: https://codepen.io/khaduch/pen/WOjMEj

Comment: I created fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/X9tgY/1576/ but its working fine. have you miss any external link

Comment: The bootstrap version is V3 sir ...  Sir the one in d link above is correct and changed right ?